# Создай и реализуй интерфейс QuestionDtoDao с методом getById, который принимает в параметрах questionId и authorizedUserId. Возвращай Optional

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Не могу сообразить как правильно реализовать хотелось бы понять как это сделать конкретного решения не нужно просто хотя бы направление в котором искать решение.

```
  @Repository
        public class QuestionDtoDaoImpl implements QuestionDtoDao {
        
            @PersistenceContext
            private EntityManager entityManager;
            @Override
           public Optional<QuestionDtoDao> getById(long questionId,long authorizedUserId){
        
        
        
            }
        
        }
    
    
    
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Schema(description = "вопросы")
    public class QuestionDto {
      @Parameter(description = "id вопроса")
      private Long id;
      @Schema(description = "заголовок вопроса")
      private String title;
      @Schema(description = "id автора")
      private Long authorId;
      @Schema(description = "имя автора")
      private String authorName;
      @Schema(description = "ссылка на изображение автора")
      private String authorImage;
      @Schema (description = "описание вопроса")
      private String description;
      @Schema(description = "количество просмотров")
      private Long viewCount;
      @Schema(description = "репутация автора")
      private Long authorReputation;
     @Schema (description = "количество ответов на вопрос")
      private Long countAnswer;
      @Schema(description = "рейтинг вопроса")
      private Long countValuable;
      @Schema(description = "дата создания вопроса")
      private LocalDateTime persistDateTime;
      @Schema(description = "дата последнего обновления")
      private LocalDateTime lastUpdateDateTime;
      @Schema(description = "кол-во голосов за вопрос")
      private Long countVote;


@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "question")
public class Question implements Serializable {

    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8765151549804433494L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "Question_seq")
    private Long id;

    @Column
    @NotNull
    private String title;

    @NotNull
    @Column
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
    private String description;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "persist_date", updatable = false)
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.LocalDateTimeType")
    private LocalDateTime persistDateTime;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "question_has_tag",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "question_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
    private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();

    @Column(name = "last_redaction_date", nullable = false)
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.LocalDateTimeType")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime lastUpdateDateTime;

    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private Boolean isDeleted;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "question", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "question", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<CommentQuestion> commentQuestions;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "question", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<UserFavoriteQuestion> userFavoriteQuestions;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "question", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<VoteQuestion> voteQuestions = new ArrayList<>();

    @PrePersist
    private void prePersistFunction() {
        checkConstraints();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    private void preUpdateFunction() {
        checkConstraints();
    }

    private void checkConstraints() {
        if (this.tags == null || this.tags.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ConstrainException("Экземпляр Question должен иметь в поле tags хотя бы один элемент");
        }
        if (this.isDeleted == null) {
            this.isDeleted = false;
        }
        try {
            if (this.user.getId() <= 0) {
                throw new EntityNotFoundException("User id must be > 0 on create or update.");
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("User id must be not null on create.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Question)) return false;
        Question question = (Question) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, question.id) &&
                Objects.equals(title, question.title) &&
                Objects.equals(description, question.description) &&
                Objects.equals(persistDateTime, question.persistDateTime) &&
                Objects.equals(user, question.user) &&
                Objects.equals(tags, question.tags) &&
                Objects.equals(lastUpdateDateTime, question.lastUpdateDateTime) &&
                Objects.equals(isDeleted, question.isDeleted);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, title, description, persistDateTime, user, tags, lastUpdateDateTime, isDeleted);
    }
}
```

Comment: И в чем проблема?

Comment: @Scruffy the Janitorне могу понять как реализовать интерфейс QuestionDtoDao с двумя параметрами

Comment: Вам надо написать запрос на hql, ток мы то как это сделаем не зная структуры. Вы хотя бы классы скинули, это же не битва экстрасенсов

Comment: Для чего id авторизации нужен? Чтоб проверить пользователя либо он связан как-то с вопросом. Если просто чтоб проверить, то какие вообще проблемы. Сначала session. get(qustion. Class, qustion id), потом уже проверяем пользователя

Comment: @Scruffy the Janitor  вообще нужно разработатьapi которое возвращает DTO вопроса по Id, dto сейчас прикреплю а только можно hql запрос?

Comment: да можно и sql  , там разница то не большая, ток пишешь заглавными и обращаешься к таблице , а не к классу.  А у вас что не hibernate?

Comment: @Scruffy the Janitor hibernate

Comment: @Scruffy the Janitor если можете посоветуйте что почитать по этому вопросу

Comment: Почитайте короче spring in action 120 страницы, и раньше . Может поможет